# Retrieving vertex path from linear-programming solution

Tags: graph, routes, linear-programming, traveling-salesman

I have been trying to solve a routing problem, like the `TSP` (traveling salesman problem) but with some twists. I have modeled the problem using linear-programming (`CPlex library`) and a directed graph (with an Origin vertex) (`Coin-Or::Lemon library`).

The linear program finds the solution, but my question lies in how to retrieve the path.
I can iterate each vertex and edge of the graph to find out which the linear program is using, so I thought I'd just start on the Origin and use the chosen edges to get to next node until I reached the Origin again.

The problem was that the CPlex path may walk through any vertex more than once. So I decided to use a recursive algorithm. But I can't quite figure it out. Here's what I've tried:

```
FindPath ( node N, path P)
    AddedAnyPath <- false
    for each edge E out of N that hasn't been used yet
        T is the target of E
        add T to P

        if findPath ( E, P )
            AddedAnyPath = true
    end for each
    
    if AddedAnyPath 
        if all edges were used
            return true
        else
            return false
        end if
    endif
end
```

This algorithm fails to find a path. If you please could point me in any direction I would be very grateful.

#### Edit

The answer provided helped me find the answer. Here's the code in `C++`:

```
bool findPath2 ( Store_Instance &T, DiNode &current, list <DiNode> &path, ListDigraph::ArcMap<bool> &usedArcs, IloCplex &cplex, ListDigraph::ArcMap<IloNumVar> &x) {
DiNode currentNode = current;
bool success = false;
int positionToInsert = 1;
while (true) {
    //Find an unvisited edge E whose value is 1.
    Arc unvisitedArc = INVALID;
    for(Digraph::OutArcIt a(T.g, currentNode); a != INVALID; ++a) {
        if(cplex.getValue(x[a]) >= 1-EPS && !usedArcs[a]) {
            unvisitedArc = a;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (unvisitedArc != INVALID) {
        //Mark edge as visited
        usedArcs[unvisitedArc] = true;
        //Get the target T of the edge
        DiNode target = T.g.target(unvisitedArc);
        //Add Edge E to the path
        list<DiNode>::iterator iterator = path.begin();
        advance(iterator, positionToInsert);
        path.insert(iterator, target);
        //Increase the iterator
        positionToInsert++;
        //If all the edges whose value is 1 are visited, stop
        bool usedAllEdges = true;
        for (ArcIt a(T.g); a != INVALID; ++a){
            if (cplex.getValue(x[a]) > 1-EPS && usedArcs[a] == false) {
                usedAllEdges = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (usedAllEdges) {
            success = true;
            break;
        }
        //Else, Set N to be T and repeat
        else currentNode = target;
    } else {
        //No arcs were found. Find a node from the path that has unvisited Arc
        positionToInsert = 0;
        DiNode target = INVALID;
        for (list<DiNode>::const_iterator iterator = path.begin(), end = path.end(); iterator != end; ++iterator) {
            DiNode v = *iterator;
            for(Digraph::OutArcIt a(T.g, v); a != INVALID; ++a) {
                if(cplex.getValue(x[a]) >= 1-EPS && !usedArcs[a]) {
                    target = v;
                    break;
                }
            }
            positionToInsert ++;
            if (target != INVALID) break;
        }

        if (target != INVALID) {
            //cout << "found lost node" << endl;
            currentNode = target;
        } else {
            success = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
return success;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to a TSP (the path) is an ordered list of vertices, that start and end at the origin, visiting each vertex. There are two possible cases.

[image]

If you have allowed a vertex to be visited twice, then in your variation, you are allowing `sub-tours'. (Case 2)
[image]

You will have variables X_nt which will be 1. (Edge variables connecting node n to node t).

If you have no subtours: Case 1, you can stop once you come back to the origin node.

It looks like you are allowing sub-tours (multiple cycles, case 2 above). If so, you have to visit *all* edges that are part of the TSP solution, whose value is 1. (Modify your code to follow any one edge out of each node to its terminal node, *one edge at a time*.)

```
Let starting n = origin node
For node n:
  Find an unvisited edge E whose value is 1. 
  Mark edge as visited
  Get the target T of the edge
  Add Edge E to the path
  If all the edges whose value is 1 are visited, stop
  Else, Set N to be T and repeat
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try what you mentioned right now, and I'll get back to you

Comment: IT WORKED ! THANK YOU !! I'm editing my question with the correct code based on what you suggested